# Can I stop Firefox from asking to refresh (message: did not use Firefox for a while)?

Tags: firefox

I use Firefox from a virtual machine to surf the web. I have a snapshot of the VM and I restore the state of the snapshot quite often, thus wiping out all the past usage.

The problem is that every time I start Firefox after a restore a message appears saying that it looks like I did not use Firefox for a while and asks to refresh.

Is there a setting to stop this message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this :

- Go in Firefox to `about:config`
- Create new boolean entry named `browser.disableResetPrompt`
- Set its value to `True`
- Exit Firefox
- Store a new snapshot and use it in the future.

Source :
[How to disable reset prompt in Firefox](http://miroslav.suchy.cz/blog/archives/2014/05/13/how_to_disable_reset_prompt_in_firefox/index.html).